# Dynamic dropdown select option first option from the service and the second option will select the doctor of the services selected.

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

//I need to do a dropdown select option where the first option will select the services in the database and when select the first option,  the second option is to select the doctor services where it will be another query. In mySQL, i have service table, doctor table and doctor services table. i hope you able to solve this issue for me as i am new in programming.

```
<?php 
include 'dbFunctions.php';
?>

<html> 
<head> 
<title>Dynamic Dropdown</title> 
<script language="javascript"> 

function setOptions(chosen) { 
  var selbox = document.myform.doctor_services; 

  selbox.options.length = 0; 
  if (chosen == "0") { 
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Select first Option','0'); 

  } 
  <?php 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service") or die(mysql_error()); 

  while(@($c=mysql_fetch_array($result))) 
  { 
  ?> 
    if (chosen == "<?=$c['service_id'];?>") { 

    <?php 
    $c_id = $c['service_id']; 
    $doctorServiceQ = "SELECT ds.doctor_service_id, d.doctor_id, d.doctor_name FROM doctor_services ds, 
                doctor d, service s WHERE ds.doctor_id = d.doctor_id AND service_id = 'c_id'";
                $doctorServiceR = mysqli_query($link, $doctorServiceQ) or die('error');

    while(@($m=mysql_fetch_array($doctorServiceR))) 
    { 
    ?> 
      selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new 
      Option('<?=$m['doctor_name'];?>','<?=$m['doctor_service_id'];?>'); 
    <?php 
    } 
    ?> 
    } 
  <?php 
  } 
  ?> 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form name="myform"><div align="center"> 


        <select name="service" size="1" 
        onchange="setOptions(document.myform.service.options 
        [document.myform.service.selectedIndex].value);"> 
        <option value="0" selected>Select a car</option> 
        <?php 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service") or die(mysql_error()); 
        while(@($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))) 
        { 
        ?> 
          <option value="<?=$r['service_id'];?>"><?=$r['service_name'];?></option> 
        <?php 
        } 
        ?> 
        </select><br><br> 


            <select name="doctor_services" size="1"> 
            <option value=" " selected>Select Option</option> 
            </select><br><br>

            <input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected" 
            onclick="alert(document.myform.doctor_services.options 
            [document.myform.doctor_services.selectedIndex].value);"> 
            </div></form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You need to populate the second select based on first select option? if yes ajax is your answer

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to populate 2nd drop down based on first drop drop down select then you get help from here is the   **[Demo](http://www.91weblessons.com/demo/countryStateCityDropDown/index.php)**

And here is the  **[Tutorial](http://www.91weblessons.com/php-ajax-country-state-city-drop-down/)**